# Как менять положение по вертикали/горизонтали у div со значением display: inline block?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Как менять положение по вертикали/горизонтали у div со значением display: inline block? `margin` не работает. Спасибо.
Ссылка на сайт для визуального примера: [shveypokrov.ru](http://shveypokrov.ru)

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #B63D32;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 96.1%;
  min-height: 202px;
  /*border*/
  border-top: 22px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
  border-left: 22px solid #000;
  border-right: 22px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border ends*/
}

.container {
  max-width: 898px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 85px;
  height: 86px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 9.85%;
}

.title__first {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.title__second {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 0.5px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  letter-spacing: -0.55px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.main__menu {
  height: 13px;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.main__menu ul li>a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -11.1%;
}

ul {
  padding-top: 11px;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 23%;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

section {
  width: 96.1%;
  height: 640px;
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
  border-left: 22px solid #000;
  border-right: 22px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -16px;
  /*border ends*/
}

.container1 {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  background-image: url(../img/fon.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  /* Для хрома */
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  /* Для лисы*/
  -o-background-size: cover;
  /* Для оперы*/
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  /* Для ИЭ*/
  background-size: cover;
  /* Для закрипления*/
  background-position: 19%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.spisok {
  height: 100%;
  width: 235px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
  border-left: 0px solid #000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}

.spisok li {
  width: 195px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 13.2px;
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu.png);
  background-size: cover;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#oblacheniya {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 9px;
}

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 40px;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}

.spisok ul li a p {
  padding-top: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#ugol {
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu_black.png);
}

.text-div {
  width: 158px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -9px;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.ryasi {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
/*Конец левого меню*/

.Nashi_Tseny {
  height: 62%;
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.text_1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

footer {
  width: 96.1%;
  height: 150px;
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
  border-left: 22px solid #000;
  border-right: 22px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border ends*/
}
```

```html
  <?php  
   require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
  ?>
  <section>
   <div class="container1"> 
     <?php  
      require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/left_menu.php';
           ?>
     <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
      <div>
        <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="text_1">
       <p>Облачения:<p>
       <p>-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong> рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
       <p>-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span></strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
       <p>Подрясники:</p>
       <p>Подризники:</p>
       <p>Рясы:</p>
       <p>Стихари:</p>
       <p>Скуфии:от 800 рублей;</p>
       <p>Камилавки:от 1700</p>
       <p>Крещальные:</p>
       <p>Облачения для храма:</p>
       <p>Вышитые кресты:</p>
       <p>Кадильный уголь:</p>

       *парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу
      </div>
     </div>
     
   </div>
  </section>
  <?php  
   require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/footer.php';
  ?>
```

Comment: Как понять margin не работает, и как надо выровнять?

Comment: @Air вообще, до этого я использовал 'position: relative', но мне тут сказали, что его надо как можно реже использовать
Тогда остается минусовать margin, но ведь это тоже неправильно, по сути

Comment: `position: relative` родителю и ребенку. Потом у ребенка меняете `top` или `bottom`

Comment: Quick Brown Fox, реже или чаще не скажу, но то что его надо использовать там где необходимо это точно...  Но есть одно большое "НО", трудно говорить о чем то и советовать в большом проекте, если бы это был минимальны какой то пример, то нет проблем, а тут сложность в том, что все что нужно и как нужно и как должно быть у тебя в голове и ни кто кроме тебя знать не может знать, и одним вопросом описать всю сут не получиться, но вот в данном примере я даже не понял вопроса... опиши в вопросе как ты хочешь что бы было...

Comment: Уберите у классов `spisok` и `Nashi_Tseny` свойство `display: inline-block;` и добавьте `float: left;`. И можете ровнять все margin-ами.

Comment: @Air Хотелось бы, чтобы "Nashy_Tseny" переместились чуть-чуть вверх и вправо

Comment: @QuickBrownFox попробуйте сделать как я описал выше. Вписывание `display: inline-block;` в Вашем случае избыточно, потому что `div` и так блочный элемент, а обтекание можно регулировать через `float`.

Comment: @DogeDev а если нужно, чтобы текст был всегда ровно по середине при масштабировании? margin:0 auto уже не использовать, если регулировать отступами

Comment: @QuickBrownFox По горизонтали? У Вас задано `margin: 0 auto;` для `text_1`. А у родительского `Nashi_Tseny` выставлено `width: 75%;`. Поэтому он выравнивает по середине тех 75% ширины.

Comment: @QuickBrownFox если нужно сделать адаптивно это все и не хочется разбираться с позиционированием и flex-ами, то лучше скачать bootstrap-grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данный пример сделан на Flex-х если не будешь выставлять размеры он буден резиновый, но flex-сы не отменяют ни размеры ни margin дальше сам все думаю справишься, можешь выставить и размеры и отступы... Надеюсь я понял тебя правильно))))

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #B63D32;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 96.1%;
  height: 640px;
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
  border-left: 22px solid #000;
  border-right: 22px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*border ends*/
  background: yellow;
}

.container1 {
  background-color: orange;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

#wrapperMenu {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: cyan;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.Nashi_Tseny {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
}

.text_1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gray;
}

h2 {
  height: auto;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.vosem_tis {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<?php  
   require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
  ?>
<section>
  <div id="wrapperMenu">
    В этоту обертку надо загружать меню
  </div>
  <div class="container1">
    <?php  
      require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/left_menu.php';
           ?>
    <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
      <div>
        <h2>Наши цены:</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="text_1">
        <p>Облачения:
          <p>
            <p>-иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">9000</span></strong> рублей с шикарными галунами</p>
            <p>-иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span class="vosem_tis">10000</span></strong> рублей<strong>*</strong></p>
            <p>Подрясники:</p>
            <p>Подризники:</p>
            <p>Рясы:</p>
            <p>Стихари:</p>
            <p>Скуфии:от 800 рублей;</p>
            <p>Камилавки:от 1700</p>
            <p>Крещальные:</p>
            <p>Облачения для храма:</p>
            <p>Вышитые кресты:</p>
            <p>Кадильный уголь:</p>

            *парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<?php  
   require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/footer.php';
  ?>
```

Comment: Почему-то максимальный margin: -40%;

Comment: Я бы просто хотел узнать, как правильно позиционировать элемент с display: inline-block, не используя position: releative/absolute;

Comment: Ты  понимаешь, что бы не использовать  position: releative/absolute и выставить элемент куда хочешь и как хочешь, у тебя должна быть внятная конструкция. я вообще не понимаю, что и как там сделал... Есть Flex- Ы  Есть Float- Ы можно по разному, но я даже тебе пример на данном примере твоем показать не могу потому что все надо менять... я тебе описал ошибки ты хотя бы BR -ы убрал..  У тебя родительский меньше  меньше дочернева.. Ну я вообще представления не имею , что ты хотел изобразить...

Comment: Необхоимо сделать следующим образом, как на картинке https://ibb.co/eQQAhm . Просто сместить. Конструкция такова: в section левое меню, а справа его нужно просто разместить блок с надписью, чтобы заголовок был по центру и отцентровка не терялась при масштабировании. Спасибо за ответы)

Comment: Quick Brown Fox, у тебя в  section что еще должно быть, левое меню в section  базируется?

Comment: Оно уже есть на скриншоте, в коде его структуры нет, потому-что он через include у меня подключен

Comment: Убрал <br>,сейчас перезалью

Comment: ты хотя бы в скрине  размеры предоставь или все покажи где должно быть боковое меню и какого размера...??

Comment: Я, наверное, вас вконец запутал)) Просто температура, наверное, некорректно объясняю) Меню уже есть, оно на скриншоте  ibb.co/eQQAhm  "Облачения", "Подризники", "Стихари" и.т.д.

Comment: Обрати внимание на id="wrapperMenu" вот в него грузи меню... выздоравливай...

Comment: если есть вопросы, спрашивай... не стесняйся...  если уж взялся, не люблю на пол пути останавливаться

Comment: разобрался?????

Comment: Да, спасибо)
Перенёс сайт полностью на флексы

Comment: )))))) умница....